# Installing a dependent module that my team wrote

Tags: powershell, dsc

How do I tell DSC that a resource/module from our internal code repository (not on a private Gallery feed), first?

Do I just use a basic Script Resource and bring the files down (somehow) into `$PSModulePath` and import them?

**Update**

There's a CmdLet called `Get-DSCResource` that will list the available resources on a system, i.e. that reside in the correct path(s), and provide some information that can be used with `Import-DscResource`, which is a 'dynamic keyword' that is placed within a `Configuration` block in a DSC script to declare the dependencies.

As for getting the resources/modules down to the target system, I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a dsc pull server then you just need to make sure that your custom module(s) are on that server. I usually put them in program files\windowspowershell\modules.

In the configuration you can just specify that you want to import your custom module and then proceed with the custom dsc resource

```
Configuration myconfig {
  Import-DSCResource customModule 
    Node somenode {
      customresource somename {

  }

 }
}
```

If you dont have a pull server and you want to push configurations then you have to make sure that your custom modules are on all target systems. you can use the [DSC file resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/fileresource?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to copy the modules or maybe just use a ps script or any other means to copy them and then use DSC for your custom configurations.